# How can I take environmental damage?

Tags: starfield

Currently, I am attempting to complete the challenge for the Environmental Conditioning perk (take X amount of environmental damage), however I can't seem to find a good place to take environmental damage.

I have tried standing on heat vents, poison vents, gone to extreme environment planets, but so far all that has netted me is cases of Lung Damage, Burns, and Frostbite. Where can I go to take some environmental damage to complete the challenge? Preferably without dying.

Comment: Without dying? Jeez you're picky. (j/k)

Comment: The only time I ever recall taking environmental damage was during a weather event (Blizzard, in my case). It turns your health bar orange as it reduces your maximum health.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to find a planet with unsafe water and go for a swim.

As you take environmental damage, your health bar will fill yellow. Note that there's a bit of delay before your take damage because your suit will (usually) have some inherent protection against whatever contaminant is present. Once that protection is overwhelmed, you'll start taking environmental damage.

[image: Taking environmental damage]

Here I've waded into the shallows on Tau Ceti II. According to my ship's scanner, the water is "biological" which I understand to mean "has biological contaminants".

[image: Scanner readout]

The environmental damage, which shows as orange on the health bar (bottom right), acts a lot like radiation in Fallout 4 -- it restricts your maximum health until you clear the damage. To clear the damage, you need to go to a shelter -- usually your ship, but maybe building an outpost will work as well (haven't tried this). Then your protection will regenerate, and the environmental damage will slowly lessen.

Answer (score 0):

Starfield planets has four different types of environmental hazards, which can cause Afflictions if you’re exposed to them for too long without adequate protection. The list of all the hazards and their corresponding icons on radar is as below:

- Thermal (Orange droplet)
- Corrosive (Yellow lines)
- Airborne (Blue half-circle)
- Radiation (Red radiation sign)

You can see the effect on the right side of your health bar, which increases over time as you are more exposed to the condition.

There are tons of planet that offer environmental damage, Generally a stronger suit has higher resistance to this, while a space suit like the Mantis space suit can help you take more damage easily.

Some planets with high environmental damage are as below:

- Saturn's moons: Saturn's moons, such as Titan and Enceladus, have unique and hazardous environments, such as Titan's methane lakes and Enceladus' water geysers.
- Akila: A planet with a dense atmosphere and high levels of toxicity.
- Jemison: A planet with extreme temperatures and active volcanoes.
- New Atlantis: A planet with a ruined city and dangerous wildlife.
- Ryujin: A planet with a harsh desert and ancient ruins.
- Settled Systems: A region of space with a variety of planets, including some with dangerous environmental hazards.

The Environmental damage depletes your suit's protection before hazarding you with the damage.

Check this page, to better understand [Environmental Damage](https://segmentnext.com/starfield-environmental-damage/) in Starfield.

Comment: One of the Ryujin faction quest line quest involved sabotaging a heating system in a building. After doing so, tons of corrosive gas is leaked into the building. I imagine this is an easy way to take environmental damage if you just so happen to need to for the skill challenge.

Comment: Most of this list is simply incorrect - Akila and Jemison don't have passive environmental damage, and you have three locations that aren't planets as well: New Atlantis (a city on Jemison), Ryujin (a megacorp on Volii), and the Settled Systems (the entire play area of the galaxy map).